# what will happen if I will renew developer account 6 months later?

Tags: developer-program

I know that my apps in app store will not be available, until I renew.

But, from the developing perspective.
what will be the different when I'm developing apps ?
Can I **develop** and **test** notifications and iCloud in the development apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Choosing a Membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) page. Scroll down to Benefits and Resources.

I believe iCloud and Push Notification fall under the 'Advanced App Capabilities' section on that list.

With a free developer account you only have access to:

- Xcode Developer Tools
- Xcode Beta Releases
- Developer Forums
- Bug Reporter
- Test on Device